# How to do serial port programming in visual studio C++ that portable between Windows & linux?

Tags: c++, linux, embedded, visual-studio-2012, serial-port

I'm writing a test program that need to access serial port. I'm doing it in Visual studio 2012 now, but I want to port to Linux later. (For using in my Pandaboard) 
Can you suggest me a way to access serial port that has almost the same interface between Win & Linux? 
I used to do it in Labview, but now I want to turn to C++
Thank  you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Boost.ASIO](http://www.boost.org/libs/asio/) is well-documented, well-tested, has been peer reviewed by thousands of people, and fully supports serial port communication in a cross-platform manner. Specific documentation can be found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/serial_ports.html).

That being said, it does assume a moderate skill level in modern C++, so if you're new to the language then the learning curve may be a bit steep.

Comment: Thanks ildjarn, It would take me a long time to learn Boost. I'm familiar with C but not C++. My First look at Boost is a little bit complicated.. There're lot of people using Boost and find it comfortable, so I think using boost is actually not as complicated as reading the document, is it true? The document on Boost website may make it hard for beginner isn't it?

Comment: BTW, can I use Boost in an embedded Linux environment like Beagle Bone or PandaBoard? thanks!

Comment: @JackSMTV : Again, the library assumes moderate knowledge of modern C++ -- consider that a hard prerequisite IMO. And yes, I have personal experience in using Boost.ASIO in an embedded environment (in conjunction with Boost.Spirit, Boost.MSM, Boost.MPL, and Boost.Fusion as a matter of fact); no worries there.

Comment: @JackSMTV : Keep in mind that Boost is not a library -- it is a _collection_ of libraries. Some are more crucial to learn than others IMO, e.g. smart pointers and Boost.Thread if you're stuck with C++03, Boost.Spirit if you're doing complex I/O, Boost.Variant and Boost.MSM for general use. And of course Boost.ASIO. :-]

Comment: Thanks ildjarn for the information, I will try to learn that first.

Comment: I found this page very helpful :) http://www.webalice.it/fede.tft/serial_port/serial_port.html

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much to a serial port interface...you should be able to wrap all of the implementation details underneath it.

```
class ISerialPort
{
public:
   void open(const std::string &serialPortName) = 0;
   void close() = 0;

   void write(const vector<char> &data) = 0;
   vector<char> read(size_t bytesToRead) = 0;
}
```

Although it isn't much of an "interface" as it is a common header that two different platforms would implement.

Edit:
Serial Ports under Linux are accessed by opening device nodes.  Such as /dev/ttyS0 (Serial Port 0).  In windows you're doing the same thing, but instead of opening a device node, you're opening a file (a COM port).  Such as COM1.

In linux you're diving into platform dependent issues such as opening device nodes.  In Linux it'll be opening files (COM ports).

Google c++ windows/linux serial port and come back with a more specific question.  You just asked about an interface;)

Comment: Thanks Ryan, can you give a more concrete example of send/receive bytes to Serial port. Sorry I'm new to C++.. :)